.NET 8 unable to send response with "application/octet-stream" header
The situation is. This endpoint needs to return the bytes of the file saved on the DB.
[HttpGet("/GetTemplate")]
[Produces("application/octet-stream")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetTemplate()
{
    try
    {
        byte[] boletoTemplate = _templateService.GetTemplate();

        HttpResponseMessage response = new(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(boletoTemplate)
        };
        
        return response;
    }
    catch (NotFoundException ex)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(ex.Message)
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(ex.Message)
        };
    }
}

But it's returning Not Acceptable.
This occurs when I put an annotation
[Produces("application/octet-stream")]

When I change to application/json, result is Ok, but the file bytes are all different.
Example of postman receiving 406 Not Acceptable

How can I get this endpoint to return application/octet-stream so that the file bytes don't get messed up on response?

catch (Exception e) { throw new Exception(e.Message); } - don't do this. Either rethrow the original exception (eg after logging) or remove the catch block - you're losing the exception context (stack trace) doing this

The 'Not Acceptable' response suggests that the server configuration (the .net 8.0 project) infers that the client (.net 5.0) will not be able to accept its response because the client didn't present an Accept header. See: the rfc - if you set an Accept header on the client indicating that it expects application/octet-stream, does this solve the problem? Comment, not an answer, as I am guessing, and haven't reproduced it myself.

Paraphrasing, a typical webserver expects that if you don't specify, what you expect to get back is text, unless you specify that you want something else. If you hit a URL that doesn't supply text, and don't say that you don't want text, you have mutually incompatible expectations that the Accept header is designed to resolve.

TomW explained the real problem. I'll just add there's no reason to explicitly create an HttpResponseMessage. Use return File(boletoTemplate,"application/otcet-stream"); directly. Don't return a BadRequest for server-side errors either. Just allowing the exception to propagate will return the correct 500 response. In production this won't include the exception text

If you do a lot of such redirections you could check Yarp, a library used to create reverse proxies. Check the Direct Forwarding example
